# Multiple Twitter accounts using Google App Script

Tags: twitter, oauth, google-apps-script

I'm experimenting with Google Apps Script and Twitter, and I'd like to be able to access multiple Twitter accounts through one spreadsheet. At the moment I've attempted the approach below (a unique OAuthService name for each Twitter account), and this kind-of works but it clunky because I have to randomly authorize one account (and not more than one) each time the script is run, and the popup dialog doesn't tell me which account (i.e. id) I'm authenticating for.

Ideally, I'd like to force each user to give Twitter permission on first use, then store that token for later use - is this possible withe Google App Script?

Thanks.

```
function oAuth(id) {

  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(NS_TWITTER + id);
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token");
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
};
```

and then

```
  var options =
  {
    "method": "GET",
    "oAuthServiceName":NS_TWITTER + id,
    "oAuthUseToken":"always",
  };

  try {

    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(feed, options);    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is possible.
To store the token values use userProperties (Docs [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/user-properties)) or CacheService wich remains for 20 minutes in cache (Docs [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service)).

Example storing token using UserProperties

```
UserProperties.setProperty('token', 'value');
var token = UserProperties.getProperty('token');
```

Example storing token using CachService

```
// Gets a cache that is private to the current user
var cache = CacheService.getPrivateCache();
cache.put('token', 'value');
var token = cache.get('token');
```

After building you cache solution you need to check if the token is valid with twitter API. If it's invalid you should require the auth again.